# td border cuts the div outside and positioned on table in ie standards

Tags: html, css

Bellow is the html code, in which the `div` gets cut by table border when page is in standards, if I remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>`  then its working fine as expected.

I want that outside `div` placed on the table in standards, this happens in IE8 standards only (IE8 quirks behaves as expected). IE11 quirks and standard also has same issue. Chrome doesn't have this kind of issues even in Standards and quirks.

I am not getting why this is happening in IE only. I just want to know the exact reason behind this behaviour and the proper solution for this.

```css
table {
  background-color: red;
}
#footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: `border` is deprecated in html5.  Use `style=` declarative instead.

Comment: Don't use inline styles. See [Separation of presentation and content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content)

Comment: why this so in IE only and not in other browsers like chrome ??

Comment: Chrome and Firefox don't have the border issue, but text in table overlaps the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```css
#footer {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
table {
  background-color: red;
}
#footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```